# Meaning of "This may be the case."

Tags: phrase-meaning

I heard "This may be the case" in the seminar many times. But I still don't know what that means.

Could someone explain the meaning of this sentence? And it would be really appreciated if you give more examples of similar expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like saying: "Maybe what you're saying is true", usually followed by 'but' as in the following conversation:

Person A: "This service is 100% secure, you run no risk of getting scammed."
Person B: "That may be the case, but I simply cannot afford it at the moment."

Hope you find this helpful.